# How do I prove that the reciprocal of the limit of a variable is the same as the limit of the reciprocal of that same variable?

Tags: calculus, finance

If $$\lim_{p\to \infty}i^{(p)} = \delta$$

and we are computing

$$\lim_{p\to \infty} \frac{1}{i^{(p)}}$$

In what way can I justify the result to be $$\frac{1}{\delta}$$

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe $\delta \neq 0$ and $i^{(p)} = 0$ for only finitely many $p$?

Comment: @EricTowers Yes. In the context ,they are used as a constant force of interest and interest compounded p-times a year respectively. The constant force cannot be zero and (I'M ASSUMING VIA MY OWN LOGIC BTW) the interest compounded infinitely many times will be 0?

Comment: @EricTowers Reading it back now, it won't be zero but will tend to zero as p tends to infinity because it is more viewed as "what the interest would be if we compounded it p times per year" as p tends to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the limit is nonzero and no terms of the sequence are zero (or you are willing to ignore the ones that are) you can work directly from the $\epsilon-N$ definition.  We are told that $\lim_{p \to \infty}i(p)=\delta$.  That means that whatever $\epsilon \gt 0$ we choose we can find an $N$ so that $p \gt N \implies |i(p)-\delta| \lt \epsilon$

Now we claim that $\lim_{p \to \infty}\frac 1{i(p)}=\frac 1\delta$  If somebody gives us an $\epsilon' \gt 0$ we need $\left|\frac 1{i(p)}-\frac 1\delta \right| \lt \epsilon'$ or $\left|\frac{\delta-i(p)}{\delta i(p)}\right| \lt \epsilon'$.  We will require that $i(p) \gt \frac 12\delta$, there is some $N_1$ that assures this.  Then we need $\left|\frac{\delta-i(p)}{\delta i(p)}\right|\lt \left|\frac{\delta-i(p)}{\delta ^2}\right| \lt \epsilon'$ or $|\delta-i(p)| \lt \delta^2 \epsilon'$.  There is some $N_2$ that assures this.  Our $N$ is then the greater of $N_1,N_2$